# OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError user_cancelled_login | The user cancelled LinkedIn login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

So I am developing a Rails application with LinkedIn authentication. The application works fine in all the cases except the case when user cancels the login.
 I have already visited all the solutions on this site could possibly help, but no luck.

I have designed a very basic login structure and I couldn't understand where to write the code to handle the exception and to redirect the failure to a particular path.
The process I have used to make my login page was: Adding gem, Adding a route to '`auth/linkedin/callback`', Adding that controller, Adding `omniauth.rb` file with provider, client id, key, scope and fields parameters.

Adding `from_omniauth` method in user model.

And finally the link in view page. Here I have no idea what to manipulate to handle the params error.  Thanks
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TICvn.png)